# CSS File manipulation with PHP

Tags: php, html, css, file

### Is it possible to edit a specific selector in a css file with php?

For example:

```
body{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

I want to change this background color after the user changes the background color of the website from the website's settings.

EDIT:

This website is used only by one user.

I am using **Laravel 5.3** if that helps.

The way it would work is, there's a color picker for the background color of the body and then when the user submits the form. Then the file manipulation will happen there.

Comment: you can check here : http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/csscolor/

Comment: I think this does not have a good UX to let users change the whole website experience! The better way is control and store what user wants by cookies or local storage, not changing the website main CSS files.

Comment: Hi Ralpaw, you could user your user globals to comunicate with you javascript and have javascript change de background to an specific color. I did something like this for a school project where user had custom themes and thats how I did it. Not sure if there are better options for php and css interactions, but thats an options. hope it helps. If you have a more concrete questions about it let us know.

Comment: If you're gonna have multiple users and they can all change their own elements, one alternative can be to write their choices to another CSS-file, store it with their userID or username or something, and check for such a file on load, and if it exists, load it as another CSS, after the standard one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like like

```
$color_name = 'green';
<body style="background-color:<?php echo color_name ; ?>">
  Body elements
</body>
```

However its not a good idea to change this with php in my opinion.You have to make a get/post request to change this. Its better to do this with jquery

```
<body class="change_backgroud_color">
  Body Elements
</body>

 $(document).ready(){
   $(".some_event_name").on("change",function(){
   $(".change_backgroud_color").css("background-color", "yellow");
  });
 }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be just a temporary change?

Comment: Yeah, but you can store it to database too and on load the page get the info and show it the user

Comment: A cleaner way to achieve this would be to base the styling on CSS classes. Include both styles in a stylesheet and apply/remove the class as required.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're being very brief and we don't know any details about your implementation (Framework for example), I would make some endpoint that would return some specific bits of css from PHP.

**Example 'css.php'**

```
//Identify your user however you normally do this.
$user = getUser();

//Retrieve the users settings however you normally do this.
$settings = getSettings($user);

function renderCss($settings){
     $cssString = "
        body{
           background-color: %s
        }
     ";
     return sprintf($cssString, $settings->background_color);
}

//Make sure the browser interprets it as css.
header("Content-type: text/css");
exit(renderCss($settings));
```

Then just include the css file like you would a regular css file

`<link id="user-styles" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.php">`

You can easily reload the style sheet like this with javascript:

```
function refresh(){
   link = document.getElementById('user-styles');
   link.href = link.href + "?t=" + new Date().getMilliseconds();
}

refresh();
```

Comment: @RalpawTato how do you identify your user? And, are you planning to save the users settings somewhere or just in a css file?